# How to completely load audio but play it later?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

So, I have an `AudioInputStream`, which reads from a `FileInputStream`. I want to close the `FileInputStream` which will close the `AudioInputStream`.

Is there any way to load the audio completely, so that I don't have to stream it directly from the file?

Comment: Audio files can be really big - are you sure you want to cache it in RAM?

Comment: yes, I am making a library to manage assets, and I already have it set up to load the asset from a file, then close the fileinputstream. Image files can also be very big, and I do the same thing with them.

Comment: Youu can read the file into memory and then create a ByteArrayInputStream on top of the memory buffer and play audio from that.

Comment: I think that while I was looking around, I found an idea something like that. The only issue is that it doesn't keep the format information, so it will throw an unsupported audio exception.

Comment: You are providing information that is relevant to your question within comments. Don't do that; instead update your question.

Comment: @Mrab Ezreb just specify the format yourself using the apropriate constructor: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#AudioInputStream(java.io.InputStream,%20javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,%20long)

Comment: alright, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in a Java [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html).

**Example:**

```
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(/*your AudioInputStream*/);
```

Make clip a field, to use it later.

Comment: man, am I dumb. I knew about clips, but I never thought to use them. Thanks a lot. can't quite accept this answer yet

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `AudioInputStream`, you can load the entire file in to a byte array:

```
static AudioInputStream load(File file) throws IOException {
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        for (int b; (b = in.read(buf)) > -1;) {
            bytes.write(buf, 0, b);
        }

        return AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

Or in Java 7:

```
static AudioInputStream load(File file) throws IOException {
    return AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
}
```